# C# convert roundtrip date string to DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, backend

I have to parse following string to DateTime object:

```
2018-03-27T14:33:54.4092769+03:00
```

I know that there are few methods that can parse string, for example DateTime.Parse() and DateTime.ParseExact(). I checked first method but there is no specification for this exact pattern.

So how can I parse this format to DateTime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-format is already supported by `DateTime.Parse/TryParse`:

```
bool valid = DateTime.TryParse(strDate, out DateTime dt); // true
```

Comment: Yes, sorry haven't noticed that format.